# Codeigniter insert_batch limitation issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-insert, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter `insert_batch()` function instead of looping the data with simple insert. Number of my rows is about 390 and just 100 of them insert as codeigniter (or mysql) doesn't allow to insert more than 100 rows in a single query.

Then I separated 100 by 100 with **array_chunk** function, like this:

```
$all_hafars = array_chunk($hafar_co,100);
foreach ($all_hafars as $hafar) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('hafar_co', $hafar);
}
```

Again only 100 of them insert! Any idea?

**Edit :** I even use simple `insert` function with **transaction**. When I use transaction, again it insert only 100 rows.

Comment: Try with transaction https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Comment: @Abdulla you mean instead of `insert_batch` I must use simple `insert` function?? But, is this an efficient way??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's queries are limited by the **`max_allowed_packet`** configuration option. It defines the absolute length limit, in characters, that a query string can be. Note that this isn't just the total size of the data being inserted, it's the entire query string. SQL commands, punctuation, spaces, etc...

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE  '%max_allowed_packet%'
```

Comment: It returns me **1048576**. So, what should I do?

Comment: You have to increase this size.

Answer (score 1):

> `insert_batch` Is going to prevent some `mysql` limit problems. I
>   think that it's related to configuration in your MySQL. The main idea is to avoid if you try to cross something.

**I suggest you to use transaction instead of insert_batch.**

You can read more about transactions here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

You can read more about your problem here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2680

Comment: you mean instead of `insert_batch` I must use simple `insert` function?? But, is this an efficient way??

Comment: @vahidnajafi, The right way it to use simple insert function IN `transaction`.
It means that you will do all insert queries together. it's better than `insert_batch();`